# CNN + LSTM + CTC for OCRing English words and alphanumeric characters

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have trained a model (cnn + lstm + ctc)for OCR and what I have observed is that it works well for words.

For example, I had trained the model with all the color names (White, Green etc) and also with alphanumeric characters like HLJH9990012, BJGH888902.

Now, whenever I have to do OCR or color names, it works fine with the new data but the OCR on alphanumeric characters just doesn't work.

For example, I gave a new image which had the characters JGTR777909 but it read it as H999.

The character distribution is when I trained the model was even.

So is LSTM good only to recognise words ? Why cant it recognise the alphanumeric characters ?

Comment: LSTM does not care what kind of chars you want to recognize. 
Therefore, something else is wrong. Please provide more information about your model. Maybe your model is not able to output such long texts as "JGTR777909" because the RNN outputs a shorter sequence? 
Further, provide a dump (e.g. CSV file) of the RNN output matrix (along with a charmap) if possible for one of the problematic cases. This could help analyzing the problem.

Comment: @Harry thanks for your feedback. I'll update my question with some data. However, this question was asked because, after I had trained about some 20K lines of words, I could see that the model performed extremely well on validation set and also inference on new words that were already trained worked well. The problem happens when a totally new set of alphanumeric characters are given and it performs bad. Also the output is variable length. I'll update the question in sometime.